# Is there a lock statement in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Does VB.NET have the equivalent of C#'s `lock` statement?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Yes, the [SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx) statement.

For example:

```
// C#
lock (someLock)
{
    list.Add(someItem);
}

// VB
SyncLock someLock
    list.Add(someItem)
End SyncLock
```

Answer (score 31):

It is called SyncLock example:

```
Sub IncrementWebCount()
    SyncLock objMyLock
        intWebHits += 1
        Console.WriteLine(intWebHits)
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called SyncLock