# How to safely access a global variable from a backgroundworker thread vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, backgroundworker

I've got a backgroundworker implemented in my program and it's accessing a global variable decalred outside the thread.  IT causes no errors but setting the checkillegalstring property and there are cross thread exceptions all over the place.  I found out that it's because it's using the global variable I've declared previously.

I can't seem to find anywhere that I can use a global variable inside my backgroundworker thread, is this possible to do?

Comment: The best solution will depend on how you use that variable. Can you post some of the code?

Comment: Post the relevant code please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is with `SyncLock`

```
Sub firstNewThread()
    SyncLock objLock
        'Access global object
    End SyncLock
End Sub
Sub secondNewThread()
    SyncLock objLock
        'Guaranteed to not be executing while block in first thread is running
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Just be aware of other pitfalls like deadlocks that may occur from this.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm just looking to read the data, no updating will be occuring on the form.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try SyncLock.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/915877/153923

For example:

```
// C#
lock (someLock)
{
    list.Add(someItem);
}

// VB
SyncLock someLock
    list.Add(someItem)
End SyncLock
```