# How can I terminate a running process on a handheld device?

Tags: windows-ce, motorola, handheld

I am no longer able to replace the old version of my exe on my handheld device (copied over from the dev machine). When I try to do so, I get:

```
Cannot copy Platypus.exe 
The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected.
```

The device is still responding, otherwise; it is not disconnected. When I try to run Platypus.exe on it now, it just "hourglasses" forever (and a day).

I have warmbooted the device, and it makes no difference. I'm trying to avoid having to cold-boot it, if at all possible.

If I could Ctrl+Alt+Del, I reckon I cound find the rogue process and kill it. I tried Start > Run... > taskmgr, but taskmgr is not recognized.

Is there a way I can accomplish this without resorting to a cold boot?

### UPDATE

I coldbooted, and I'm still getting the same thing (won't let me copy)...

### UPDATE 2

Have my ActiveStync connection settings gone haywire? I don't know what they should be for sure, but I do what they are right now:

[image]

### UPDATE 3

It's only certain files that refuse to be copied over. For example, I tried to copy over two .SDF files - one replaced the other one fine, but the next one gave me the err as above. I then tried to delete the file which would not be replaced, and got, "bla.SDF could not be deleted. The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected."

Neither one of these is true. It's another "or" but neither it nor I know what the problem actually is. It *does* seem as if certain files are in "limbo" and need to be released - but if a cold boot won't do it, what will?

### UPDATE 4

As my youngest son would say, "Okay, then!" (in a mildly mocking tone of dumbfounded disbelief).

For some reason, as quickly as my it-won't-allow-me-to-copy-over-a-new-exe-any-more OOME (Out Of Mind Experience) occurred,

now it all of a sudden is letting me again - the same old .exe finally allowed itself to be deleted, and the same new .exe I've been trying

to copy over for more than a day finally agreed to be copied over.

Why, I don't know. I did run a quick-and-dirty util I slapped together on the handheld device to search and destory instances of my .exe/.dll pair, but it didnt' find them. See the Update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167054/how-can-i-reference-processinfos-members-and-processce-in-my-windows-ce-util) for all the gory details.

Comment: Sounds like it is an ActiveSync issue

Comment: Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Yeah, something is really messed up - even trying to copy an .SDF file is giving me that err msg now...

Comment: Try turning off RNDIS. Start->Settings->Connections->USB to PC. Uncheck *Enable advanced network functionality*. Have you tried itsutils [pkill](http://itsme.home.xs4all.nl/projects/xda/tools.html)?

Comment: @PaulH: You mean on the handheld, right? I see Start > Settings > Network and Dialup Connections, and then "Make New Connection" and "USB CABLE:"

"USB CABLE:" has "IP Address" and "Name Server" tabs. I have "Specify an IP Address" selected in "IP Address" and in "Name Server" I only have "Primary DNS" set up (to "127.0.0.1").
IOW, I see no "Enable advanced network functionality" checkbox.

Comment: Oh. You have *Windows CE*. My brain was on *Mobile*. I don't think there is a nice button to switch from RNDIS to Serial ActiveSync in CE. You might be able to switch by [changing the default function driver from RNDIS to Serial_Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895481.aspx).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this hasn't been changed recently, so I'm afraid to attempt such a thing; it would seem to be a "shot in the dark."

Comment: You haven't yet said what *has* been changed recently.
You can always change this value back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Nothing was changed, AFAIK, but of course that doesn't necessarily mean that nothing has changed - just that I don't know it if it has. I tried to look into that, but am prevented to so far. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002536/how-can-i-view-edit-my-registry-settings-on-a-windows-ce-6-device

Comment: The other things I can think of to do are to try another computer and try updating your PC's USB drivers. Is a cold boot a reset to factory default on your CE device? If not, and nothing else works, try that.

Comment: I tried updating the drivers, but Windows said all of them were already up-to-date. Yes, a cold boot takes me back to a "my custom software has to be reinstalled" state. I've already tried that.

Comment: USB drivers won't typically come from windows update. They're going to be manufacturer specific. If you have a Dell, for example, then you would go to http://support.dell.com to get updated USB drivers. Come to think of it, is your WinCE device plugged in to a Super Speed USB 3.0 port? If so, try to find a High Speed USB 2.0 port instead. Flaky USB 3.0 firmware and drivers can cause a lot of problems.

Comment: It wasn't Windows Update that I used; it was Device Manager. I right-clicked on each driver to update, and in each case it told me that they already were up-to-date.

Comment: How do I determine whether the USB port is 2.0 or 3.0 (or something else)? I have four USB ports on my PC's tower; I assume that they are all the same, but I'll try using a different one to see if that makes any difference...

Comment: More specifically about how I verified driver versioning: [computer name] > Device Manager > System Devices > Universal Serial Bus Controllers > right-click > Update Driver Software > Search automatically...

Comment: That will only look for drivers that are *already on your system*. To actually update your drivers you will still need to go to your manufacturer's website and download an update (if one is available). USB 3.0 ports will have an SS next to the typical USB icon. They may also be colored blue. To know if your motherboard supports them look for an XHCI driver in device manager.

Comment: I did go to dell (the one you referred to earlier) and updated everything according to their automatic process. Still, though, I really doubt this is the issue as it went from working one minute to not working the next.

Comment: Have you tried using a different computer? If you're using a hub try going directly in to the PC. Maybe your USB cable is going bad - try a new one. That's, unfortunately, the end of my ideas.

Comment: Thanks, PaulH; it must be something to do with the handheld device, because I can copy on/to a different one...tried a different USB cable - no diff.